# Applescript : generate a new list based on existing list

Tags: applescript, macos

my script is generating a list (random number of items) and for each item I like to add a colour.

I can do it manually :

```
> set myList to {{"demo", "#5cdf64"}, {"icloud.com", "#FFFF00"}, {"more
> random e.g", "#FF0000"}}
```

but how can I add a different colour automatically to the list and based on the number of item on the first list?

I know how to count the primary list and do an action for each items :

```
set listSize to count of myList

set theList to {"demo", "demo1", "demo2", "demo2"}
repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    set theCurrentListItem to item a of theList
    -- Process the current list item

end repeat
```

I think I'm nearly there the only thing is I'm not adding but replacing the items :

```
set theList to {"Demo", "ok", "blabla", "demo2"}
set ColortheList to {"5cdf64", "FFFF00", "FF0080", "FF1000"}
set myNewList to ""

repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    set theCurrentListItem to item a of theList
    set myNewList to {item a of theList, item a of ColortheList}

end repeat
```

also tried

```
copy {item a of theList, item a of ColortheList} to myNewList
```

Comment: I'm somewhat confused on your color selection. Are you wanting the next color in the list or are you wanting to randomly select a color? Are you also wanting it to randomly add one or more colors?

Comment: Sorry, I have a list of keywords and I want to add a different colours for each of them. but I can create the list of colours already and add them for each keyword of my first list

Comment: Give me a sec and let me finish this answer and tell me if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting `myNewList` to return a list of lists I think you're trying to do:

```
set theList to {"Demo", "ok", "blabla", "demo2"}
set ColortheList to {"5cdf64", "FFFF00", "FF0080", "FF1000"}
set myNewList to {}

repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    copy ({item a of theList, item a of ColortheList}) to the end of the |myNewList|
end repeat

return myNewList
```

A little fun with `random number`. You can modify the color selection and then randomly add to a list:

```
set theList to {"Demo", "ok", "blabla", "demo2", "foobar"}

set colorList to {"5cdf64", "FFFF00"}
set colorLength to length of colorList

set myNewList to {}

repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    set colorPick to random number from 1 to colorLength
    copy ({item a of theList, item colorPick of colorList}) to the end of the |myNewList|
end repeat

return myNewList
```

If you're wanting a string approach try:

```
set theList to {"Demo", "ok", "blabla", "demo2"}
set ColortheList to {"5cdf64", "FFFF00", "FF0080", "FF1000"}
set myNewList to ""

repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    set result to ({item a of theList, item a of ColortheList})
    set myNewList to myNewList & (result & " ")
end repeat
```

The above can be modified in the `result`. Let me know if I'm understanding you or if you're needing something different.